# c# TPL TransfromBlock that builds a collection

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow

I have a series of Transform Blocks that moving data down the pipeline.

```
 var getPdfFiles = new TransformManyBlock<string[], string>(files =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finding pdf files.....");

                var pdfFilePaths = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

                Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
                {
                    pdfFilePaths.Enqueue(file);
                });

                return pdfFilePaths;
            });

            var generateBitmapFromPdfMemoryStream = new TransformBlock<string, Bitmap>(filePath =>
            {
                return _pdfConverterService.ConvertPdfToBitmapAsync(filePath);
            });

            var generateQRCodeResponseFromBitmap = new TransformBlock<Bitmap, QRCodeResponse>(bitmap =>
            {
                return _barcodeService.Read(bitmap);
            });
```

At the point that i receive each QRCodeResponse i need to then add a new item derived from the data in the QRCodeResponse to a collection. An Item called BatchItem.

I'm not sure how i an to build this collection. I also need to pass this collection further down the pipeline when it is complete.

Comment: What do you mean `when it is complete`? When completion propagates all the way down to `generateQRCodeResponseFromBitmap` or something else?

Comment: as each QRResponse comes in, i need to create a new object called BatchItem that stores infor from the QRResponse, this object needs adding to a collection. List<BatchItem>

Comment: That was clear. When do you want to send it down the pipeline though? And why put it in a collection? Why not use a BatchBlock for example?

Comment: Further down the pipline i need to create an xml file that represents the collction of Batch Items

Comment: I'll repeat the question. *When* do you want to send that collection down the pipeline? When a specific request arrives? When `generateQRCodeResponseFromBitmap` shuts down? What if it takes 1 hour before completion reaches the block?

Comment: When generateQRCodeResponseFromBitmap shuts down

Comment: Why not just send each *item* downstream and write it out to the XML file? You don't need to write *all* items at once. You *can* write a custom block [as shown in the sliding window example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-dataflow-block-type), which sends the buffer downstream every X items

Comment: i will try that, with each concurrent thread be able to access the xml file? wil it not get locked?

Comment: YOu are using *Dataflow*. You don't need to worry about concurrency. You can create an `ActionBlock` that appends to a text file.

Comment: Thanks for that!